# How is merging registry file different than manually updating the registry value?

Tags: windows-registry

If I want to update the value for a registry key, I can manually change the value or I can use a .reg file by doing RightClick -> Merge. Will there be any difference if I use either one of them instead of the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no difference AFAIK. Additionally, you can double-click a .reg file to import/merge it into the registry as well.